# Is rollback supposed to work on the mobile site?

Tags: support, bug, edits, rollbacks

When I click to edit a post on mobile, there is a drop down list of previous edits at the top. However, it does not seem as though it does anything.

Is this just for informational use, or is it broken?

I am using a Verizon Droid Pro, Android 2.3.3; Android Browser or Dolphin HD behave the same.

I can edit fine; just rollback does not work. Choosing any item in the dropdown has no effect at all; if no edits are submitted, nothing is edited. If edits are submitted, they are applied.

<sub>Oooh, I just earned my very first Tumbleweed badge from this. I didn't mean to, though. Honest!</sub>

Incidentally; I just tried it out on Firefox in the mobile view, and the same behavior prevails. So it doesn't seem like it's the browser.

Comment: Repro on mobile safari on your post (note I do not have edit privilege on meta, though) - drop down, select a version - nothing changes.

Comment: From what I can see, the full site rollback view comes up on mobile.

Comment: @Oded nope. I just reproduced, will add screenshots. (also happens in mobile theme on desktop computer)

Comment: I was about to up-vote this post, as I remember experiencing this. Then I realized I have committed *never* to upvote questions by this user. Ever.

Comment: @Oded this isn't related to mobile site theme, I just noticed it also happens in the full site. Choosing a revision does not load that revision (as I guess it should?)